# Jetty Plugin - docBase Equivalent

Tags: configuration, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a directory C:\documents\ and I would like its files and sub-directories to be accessible by visiting `http://localhost/something/`? Using Tomcat, I know that I can use

```
<Context docBase="/documents" path="/somthing" />
```

How can this be done using the Maven Jetty Plugin? I'm using the plugin version as described below:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
      <webDefaultXml>src/test/resources/webdefault.xml</webDefaultXml>
      <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
      <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
    </configuration>
    <version>7.0.0pre1</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by going to a later version of the plugin with making the following changes to my configuration (pom.xml) file:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
      <webDefaultXml>src/test/resources/webdefault.xml</webDefaultXml>
      <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
      <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
      <contextHandlers>
        <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
          <contextPath>/documents</contextPath>
          <resourceBase>/something</resourceBase>
        </contextHandler>
      </contextHandlers>          
    </configuration>
    <version>8.1.5.v20120716</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```